# How to use Rails file_field to reject .pdf files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, pdf, input, upload

I only want to accept png, gif, and jpeg so I have the below on a file_field but it still accepts pdfs

```
file_field "form", "logo", accept: 'image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg'
```

Answer (score 2):

Tell it that it is an image.

```
file_field(:post, :image, accept: 'image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg')
```